Old animated movie in which three heroes (two men and one woman) push a big alien into the Sun
There was a animation that had three heroes; two men and one woman. I remember that they finally pushed a big alien into the Sun!
Mount Rushmore also was in this movie but the mouth of his face could be open to hide heroes. 
Anybody remember the name of the movie? (Animation.)

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Also, was the animation hand-drawn (2D)? Computer-generated (3D)? Something else?

old man, boy and a girl in the first season. In the different series, the same boy and girl become young adults, so it is young woman, her boyfriend and young man (grown up boy). Ben 10 is the show. Mount Rushmore gets destroyed occasionally :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F35iHxIeqDU

Does this have one of the faces from Mt Rushmore (or an equivalent) moving backward into the mountain, and becoming part of the giant (alien?), which needs to be defeated? Is one of the girls working on sculpting a face on the mountain? I don't remember the title, but I remember these things, and if it's the one you are thinking of, it might help someone else get the name. The one I am thinking of aired (in my region, at least) some time in the 1980's (maybe early 1990's), and was hand-drawn or cell-type animation, in 2D.

It was 2D / and 1990 since maybe 1998

I watched it 2003. But it produced older
